# Работа с файловыми системами UNIX

Tags: ubuntu, unix, файловая-система, fdisk

Среди всех смонтированных файловых систем найти те, которые имеют наибольший размер свободного пространства. Записать информацию в файл: имя устройства, размер, тип файловой системы.

Comment: на shell - обработать команду df -h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ df -aPT | sort -nk 5 | awk 'END{print $1,$3,$2}' > файл
```

пример содержимого файла:

```
/dev/sda6 1452241280 xfs
```